# PyXML on Ubuntu

Tags: python, xml

I just completed a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10 and I'm trying to run some scripts that use xml and xpath.  I get an error from inside PyXML.

I think this is an install error.  To get this installed I did the following:

```
prompt> sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev   # The next line wouldn't install without this.
prompt> sudo easy_install PyXML
```

-------BEGIN ERROR---------
    username@ubuntu:~/data/code$ MyScript.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/data/code/app/trunk/MyScript.py", line 17, in <module>
    from xml import xpath
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_xmlplus/xpath/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from pyxpath import ExprParserFactory
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_xmlplus/xpath/pyxpath.py", line 59, in <module>
    from xml.xpath.ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath import ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyXML-0.8.4-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/_xmlplus/xpath/ParsedAbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath.py", line 31
    as = ParsedAxisSpecifier.ParsedAxisSpecifier('descendant-or-self')
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

-------------END ERROR-------------------

I'm about at my limits with PyXML.  I simply want to read an xml file and read/write data with xpath.  Is there a simpler library that will easily work out of the box?  Or any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-lxml` http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyXML should have been written for very old version of Python (< 2.4) and it used one of the later keywords 'as' as its variable. If your requirement is simple, you can just use [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from Python Standard library which has support for [XPath](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm) expressions. An example is [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-matters28/#N102CF).

For using the standard library module, do:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, if you really need PyXML (i.e. legacy code that you don't have the time to port right now), just changing `as` in the two places it is used to some other variable name will do.

Additionally, I noticed that Gentoo added the method `use_pyxml()` to PyXML which explicitly needs to be called; so the standard library XML modules are not used. See [here](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/gentoo/dev/230817) if that is of interest.