# Need source code for _xmlplus in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, python-2.4

We were using Python 2.4 in our application. Now we are migrating to 2.7.8.

In our code, we had used **Sax2** and **xpath** functionality from "**_xmlplus**" library.

**Approach 1:**
We started off by re-writing the parsing logic used in all those files (ie files where Sax2 and xpath were used), but this is a tedious job.

**Approach 2:**
Use _xmlplus for 2.7 version. For which  we need the source code for "**_xmlplus**". So that we can build the library.      (We were not able to find the source code in web)

Can anyone please suggest the right approach, which we should take ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `_xmlplus` is a package from `PyXML` library, so the source is available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/files/pyxml/0.8.4/PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz/download). However note that PyXML is no longer maintained (last files are from 2004).

Comment: Thanks Axarydax,
It looks like our problem is solved.

Comment: PyXML is not maintained any more. Taking the code will not work as it is. You have to modify few placeses as mentioned in below link. "as" is a keyword in python :)now.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11278231/430294